# how can I replace Jquery plugin calls which uses 'on'?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a project which uses many plugins.  However, some are reliant on older versions of JQuery . The plugin I intend to use is dependent on JQuery 1.7 as it uses 'on' for event binding.

How can I modify the plugin so that it will work with JQuery 1.6? If I upgrade to JQuery 1.7 it will break other parts of my project that are dependant on the plugins.  Or is there a better way to deal with this scenario?

Comment: Should just be able to replace `on` with `bind` in most cases? `$.on('click', function() { });` is roughly the same as `$.bind('click',function() { });`

Comment: Can you extend the jQuery object with your own very basic `.on()` method, then bind an event as usual?

Comment: But normally plug-in that works with jQuery 1.6 should work with the latest stable version of jQuery (i.e. 1.7.1, I guess) Dependency on earlier versions sounds strange

Comment: Be mindful of the fact that it may be using `on()` to bind to elements in the future (much like `delegate()` and `live()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have to look at  each call to be sure, but you can easily replace [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) calls with [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (expecially when `on()` is used for newly added elements

```
 .delegate( selector, eventType, handler(eventObject) )

 .on( events [, selector], handler(eventObject) )
```

basically you have to switch the first two arguments. Otherwise you could load jQuery 1.7 just for the plugin and use `$.noConflict(true)`

```
    $jq = $.noConflict(true);
    //replace all $ in the plugin with $jq
```

Comment: I think $jq = $.noConflict(true); is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

> As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method. For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to use event delegation. More information on event binding and delegation is in the .on() method.

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

I would try to alter the older plugins to work with 1.7+ though. Seems more rewarding.